# Powershell Rename a dynamic key in JSON file

Tags: json, powershell

I'm using the invoke RestMethod in Powershell to call an API which returns the following JSON response:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "results": [
        {
            "key": "roles",
            "id": "1180325"
        },
        {
            "key": "roles",
            "id": "1182095"
        }
    ],
    "roles": {
        "1180325": {
            "name": "L1",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2020-03-26T03:47:19-07:00",
            "updated_at": "2020-03-26T03:47:19-07:00",
            "id": "1180325"
        },
        "1182095": {
            "name": "L2",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2020-03-30T01:09:56-07:00",
            "updated_at": "2020-03-30T01:09:56-07:00",
            "id": "1182095"
        }
    },
    "meta": {
        "count": 2,
        "page_count": 1,
        "page_number": 1,
        "page_size": 20
    }
}
```

The list of objects with a dynamic name is causing me issues with joins that I'm trying make so I would like to convert "roles" to an array, and skip the first object list so the result would look like this

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "results": [
        {
            "key": "roles",
            "id": "1180325"
        },
        {
            "key": "roles",
            "id": "1182095"
        }
    ],
    "roles": [
        {
            "name": "L1",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2020-03-26T03:47:19-07:00",
            "updated_at": "2020-03-26T03:47:19-07:00",
            "id": "1180325"
        },
        {
            "name": "L2",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2020-03-30T01:09:56-07:00",
            "updated_at": "2020-03-30T01:09:56-07:00",
            "id": "1182095"
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "count": 2,
        "page_count": 1,
        "page_number": 1,
        "page_size": 20
    }
}
```

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `psobject` hidden memberset to access the properties of the `roles` property:

```
# Json -> PSObject
$object = $json |ConvertFrom-Json

# Re-assign list of property values to `roles`
$object.roles = $object.roles.psobject.Properties.Value

# PSObject -> Json
$object |ConvertTo-Json
```

If you want to skip the first item in the collection, use [`Select-Object -Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object#parameters):

```bsh
$object.roles = $object.roles.psobject.Properties.Value |Select -Skip 1
```

Comment: That was almost perfect Thank you!
The only thing I did to change the output, which gave me the format I wanted, plus a load of additional ids... was to include a remove line.

$object.roles=$object.roles.psobject.Properties.Value

$object.roles=$object.roles.psobject.Properties.Remove($object.roles.psobject.Properties)

Comment: @Christy Sorry, I completely missed the removal part, updated the answer :)